# Cant get into wp-admin page (cloudflare, nginx)

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cloudflare

I have a wordpress website that is running on Nginx behind cloudflare DNS. I have used "set_real_ip_from" for all cloudflare ips in nginx.conf. When i try to access my website i can see my real ip in the logs. I have changed the default wordpress admin login directory from wp-admin to my directory name. I only want specific ips to be allowed to login to my wordpress but with this in my websites config, server block: `location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login|mydirectory) {
        allow my.real.ip;
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }`
 i cant seem to access wordpress admin and i get 404. If i delete this block everything is working fine so i guess im typing something wrong ? i looked around on this forum with some different variations but none of them seem to work. They either allow me to access to wp-admin but then anyone can access or it blocks everyone.

**EDIT**
Unfortunately i couldnt get it to work no matter what i tried so what i did was deleted the location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login|mydirectory) block, reloaded nginx config, logged in to wordpress, disabled wp-admin change directory plugin, then went back and re-added the location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login|mydirectory) block inside it i added location ~ .php$ { as @Michael Hampton suggested and now i can access my wordpress admin page by using "wp-admin" url. Dont know why it didnt work with the custom url but i guess this will do since nginx will block anyone else trying to access it tho it would have been interesting to know why it didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

You get a 404 because you specifically asked for a 404 for all requests matching that `location`.

```
    return 404;
```

You will need to remove this statement if you want to receive anything other than a 404.

Further, you will need to place a nested `location` within that `location` to process PHP files.

```
location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login|mydirectory) {
    ...
    location ~ .php$ {
        ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am fully aware why i get 404 because as you said i set it that way. My question was why i get 404 even tho my ip is set to allow. I had to resort to something else to make this work unfortunately :/

Comment: Again, you get a 404 because you asked for a 404.

Comment: My bad i thought if i use return after deny thats what everyone else would get :/